# Creating a data frame from a character vector in R

Tags: xml, regex, r, stringr

I have some data in text form, taken from a webpage. It's quite lengthy but follows the form:

```
<p><span class="monthyear">Jan 2001</span>
<br><b>Foo text (2)</b></p>
<p><span class="monthyear">Nov 2006</span>
<br><b>Bar text (29)</b>
<br><b>More bar text (4)</b>
<br><b>Yet more bar text (102)</b></p>
<p><span class="monthyear">Apr 2004</span>
<br><b>Further foo text (1)</b>
<br><b>Combination foo and bar text (41)</b></p>
```

I want to extract the relevant parts of this into a data frame, like so:

```
  monthyear          info  n
1  Jan 2001      Foo text  2
2  Nov 2006      Bar text 29
3  Nov 2006 More bar text  4
```

...but I'm not sure how to do it. If I have the html in a character vector called text I can extract the **monthyear** data using a function from the stringr package:

```
monthyear <- str_extract_all(
text[1],perl("(?<=\\\"monthyear\\\">).*?20[0-9]{2}")
)
```

and I could extract the **info** and **n** data in the same sort of way, but given that there are multiple **info** and **n** entries for each **monthyear** entry, I'm not sure how to combine them. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: I'd take a look at the `XML` package and use its parsing functions (specifically `htmlTreeParse`) instead of trying to `regex` your way back to data.

Comment: Obligatory link to [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1222578)

Comment: My God. Have I really made such a schoolboy error?

Comment: @patabongo and your xml is really bad formatted to be easily parsed!

Comment: Badly formatted HTML?  That's unpossible!

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a lot I can do about that, it's the data I've been given.

Comment: @Justin in general yes...I saved his example to a file..I try to use XmlTreeParse...I tried to remove all the <br> ...I failed to parse it..I think here you need to use xmlSApply with xpath given by the browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't always control the quality of our data sources, so we have to resort to some tedious manual processing. (Some people say that the majority of a data analyst's time is spent in cleaning data, and not in analysis.)

As already noted in the comments, regular expressions aren't the best tools for working with HTML, because HTML, in general, isn't really a *regular* language (I think it's called a *context-free language*). But, if the HTML sources are somewhat *regular* (as they are in the example data you've provided), you might still be able to use them effectively.

Here's a step-by-step example. I've added HTML header tags to your example text and stored it here: http://ideone.com/O1PC05

1. Read in your data using `readLines`

   ```
   x1 <- readLines("http://ideone.com/plain/O1PC05")
   ```
2. Isolate the "body" of the web page

   ```
   bodycontent <- grep("<body>|</body>", x1)
   x2 <- x1[(bodycontent[1]+1):(bodycontent[2]-1)]
   ```
3. `grepl` returns a `TRUE` or `FALSE` for if "monthyear" was found in a given line. Use `cumsum` to create "groups", and `split` to convert the character vector to a list.

   ```
   x3 <- split(x2, cumsum(grepl("monthyear", x2)))
   ```
4. You can do the following in multiple steps if you prefer. The basic idea is to `lapply` over your list, replace all your HTML tags with tabs, and replace your brackets with tabs. After that you can use `read.delim`, but expect to get a lot of columns that are FULL of `NA` values since we're inserting a lot more tabs than we need.

   This is most likely where you will fail for several reasons. (1) It assumes that the source data is indeed well structured... (2) but, the text itself might have brackets... (3) or, there might be other content in the body, including script tags, table tags, and so on that will be read in and tried to be processed.

   ```
   x4 <- read.delim(header = FALSE,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    strip.white = TRUE, 
                    sep = "\t", 
                    text = 
                      unlist(lapply(x3, 
                                    function(x) {
                                      temp <- gsub("<(.|\n)*?>", "\t", x)
                                      paste(gsub("[()]", "\t", temp), 
                                            collapse="\t")
                                      })))
   ```
5. I mentioned that in step 4, we will end up with a lot of junk columns. Let's get rid of those.

   ```
   x5 <- x4[apply(x4, 2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))]
   ```
6. And, now, let's name the columns in a more meaningful way. We know that the first column will be the "monthyear" variable by design, and the others *should* be "info" and "n", so we can do some basic `rep`s wrapped in `paste` to get our variable names. While we're at it, we'll use `as.yearmon` from the "zoo" package to convert our "monyear" variable to actual dates, allowing us to sort and do other nifty things that we can do with actual dates.

   ```
   myseq <- ncol(x5[-1])/2 # We expect pairs of columns, right?
   names(x5) <- c("monthyear", 
                  paste(rep(c("info", "n"), myseq), 
                        sep(1:myseq, each = 2), sep = "."))
   library(zoo)
   x5$monthyear <- as.Date(as.yearmon(x5$monthyear, "%b %Y"))
   x5
   #    monthyear           info.1 n.1                       info.2 n.2            info.3 n.3
   # 1 2001-01-01         Foo text   2                               NA                    NA
   # 2 2006-11-01         Bar text  29                More bar text   4 Yet more bar text 102
   # 3 2004-04-01 Further foo text   1 Combination foo and bar text  41                    NA
   ```
7. If you really wanted your data in long form, use `reshape`:

   ```
   x6 <- reshape(x5, 
                 direction = "long", 
                 idvar = "monthyear", 
                 varying = 2:ncol(x5))
   ```
8. Do some optional cleanup, like ordering the output by date, resetting your row names, and dropping incomplete cases:

   ```
   x6 <- x6[order(x6$monthyear), ]
   rownames(x6) <- NULL
   x6[complete.cases(x6), ]
   #    monthyear time                         info   n
   # 1 2001-01-01    1                     Foo text   2
   # 4 2004-04-01    1             Further foo text   1
   # 5 2004-04-01    2 Combination foo and bar text  41
   # 7 2006-11-01    1                     Bar text  29
   # 8 2006-11-01    2                More bar text   4
   # 9 2006-11-01    3            Yet more bar text 102
   ```

Anyway, try it out, and modify as needed. My guess is that at some point, you'll have to open up the files in a plain text editor and do some preliminary cleanup there before you can proceed.

Comment: Brilliant. I've been stumped by this for a week or more. Now I can get going on it. Thanks!